# value y error with gnuplot. I can't see it

Tags: gnuplot

I have these error in gnuplot code: "line 0: all points y value undefined!"

The conf is:

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal png
set xdata time
set terminal png size 1024,768
set autoscale y
set output "kk.png"
set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d"
set xrange ["12/04/2015":"12/05/2015"]
plot './datos_2978.dat' using 1:2 title 'cpu' with line
```

And data:

```
12/04/15,28
27/04/15,25
05/05/15,17
11/05/15,16
```

Could you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that your timefmt string is incorrect, you are setting `"%Y/%m/%d"`, but the data is `"%d/%m/%Y"`.

Furthermore you should define your xrange like this:

```
set xrange ["12/04/15":"12/05/15"]
```

Comment: The date format should be `%d/%m/%y` (lower case `y`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I missed `set yrange[xxx:yyyy]`.

Comment: Sorry. Now I cant paint it but I can't see the values in y axis. Any help?

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if the problem is solved, or delete the question. Then you can as another question with the new problem.